# radioButton() choices with HTML and shinyjs::reset()

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I aim to get an `radioButton()` input with HTML in its labels *and* a reset functionality.

I started with the following, as `radioButtons()` does not allow HTML for the labels.

```
 library(shiny)
 library(shinyjs)

 ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(

   useShinyjs(),
   tags$div(id = "form",
   tags$div(HTML('
                 <div id="rating" class="form-group shiny-input-radiogroup shiny-input-container">
                 <label class="control-label" for="rating">Your Rating:</label>
                 <div class="shiny-options-group">
                 <div class="radio">
                 <label>
                 <input type="radio" name="one" value="1"/>
                 <span><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                 </label>
                 </div>
                 <div class="radio">
                 <label>
                 <input type="radio" name="two" value="2"/>
                 <span><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                 </label>
                 </div>
                 </div>
                 </div>'))),

   actionButton("feedback_btn", "send feedback", icon = icon("send", lib = "font-awesome")),
   htmlOutput("Ratingout")
 ))

   server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
     output$Ratingout <- renderText({
       paste("The Rating was ", input$rating)
     })

     observeEvent(input$feedback_btn, {
       reset("rating")

     })
   })

   shinyApp(ui, server)
```

but I ran into two Problems:

- I can not access the `input$Ratingout`value and
- It seems that I didn't use `shinyjs::reset()`in the correct way; as I want to reset the buttons in a way, that there is *no* selection after pressing the button.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `bind` inputs to shiny to use it on server side.

On my mind easily to overwrite shiny `radioButtons`

But in help you can see :

> If you need to represent a "None selected" state, it's possible to
>   default the radio buttons to have no options selected by using
>   selected = character(0). However, this is not recommended, as it gives
>   the user no way to return to that state once they've made a selection.
>   Instead, consider having the first of your choices be c("None
>   selected" = "").

So beter to use 0 as default value ( `reset` not work with `character(0)`)

## Example

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

edit_button=function(rb){

  for( i in 1:length(rb$children[[2]]$children[[1]])){
    value=as.numeric(rb$children[[2]]$children[[1]][[i]]$children[[1]]$children[[1]]$attribs$value)
    if(!is.na(value)&value>0){
    rb$children[[2]]$children[[1]][[i]]$children[[1]]$children[[2]]$children[[1]]=HTML(paste(rep('<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>',value),sep = "",collapse = ""))
    }
    }
  rb

}




ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  edit_button( radioButtons("rate_","Rate",choices = list("None selected"=0,'one'=1,"two"=2))),
  useShinyjs(),
  actionButton("feedback_btn", "send feedback", icon = icon("send", lib = "font-awesome")),
  htmlOutput("Ratingout")
           ))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$Ratingout <- renderText({
    paste("The Rating was ", input$rate_)
  })

  observeEvent(input$feedback_btn, {
    reset("rate_")
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: OK - this is already usable for me! In my usecase the (even) better solution would be the (not recommended) version that the inital and reseted state is, that no button is highlighted. But my js-knowledge is close to zero ...